# Why does scale_y_continuous work better with pie charts than bar charts?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can create a pie chart from my material that seems to represent the data accurately. I write:

```
pie_urval<-ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=factor(1), fill=urvalsgrupp)) +
  geom_bar(width=1, position = position_fill()) +
  coord_polar("y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

And I get:

[image]

Then I try the same thing with bar charts:

```
ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=gymnasiegrov)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

And I get:

[image]

For some reason the percentages are (I would assume) 100 times larger than expected. Why does this method work for pie charts and not for bar charts, and what can I do to correct the problem?

Small excerpt (data used for bar chart):

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 
    8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 11L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
    "Hotell- och Restaurang", "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
    "naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
    "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
    "estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:20)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Large excerpt (data used for bar chart):

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 
    8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 
    3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 
    7L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
    9L, 8L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
    7L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 
    9L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 7L, 
    6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
    7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
    "Hotell- och Restaurang", "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
    "naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
    "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
    "estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -154L
), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:154)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the y value under geom_bar a proportion, so that scales::percent converts it.

```
ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=gymnasiegrov)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + 
coord_flip()+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, but why don't I need to take this step in the pie chart? Does "ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=factor(1), fill=urvalsgrupp))+geom_bar(width=1, position = position_fill())" implicitly convert the y values to percentages?

Comment: Yes, when you pass it to coord_polar("y"), it converts the "y" into something like a proportion.. Let me pull it out from the ggplot object

Comment: Sorry I did not fully understand your question, so if you do 
 ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=factor(1),fill=gymnasiegrov)) + geom_bar(width=1,position = position_fill())

Comment: You see that it basically creates a stacked barplot, with the y-axis already in proportions (0-1). Then passing it to coord_polar is just "spreading" it into a circle

Comment: Ahhh allright. Thanks for your time and efforts! Marking this as correct answer :)

Comment: The reason you cannot use the same strategy with your barplot, is that if you do position = position_fill()), with different bars, it doesn't add up to 1..

Comment: The code you have for pie chart is a clever way to first create a stacked barplot, and spread it basically.